# Can't connect MongoDB Atlas cluster to a Spring boot app

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-mongodb

When trying to just make sure the connect is working, this error arises.

[Error that pops up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNcur.png)

This is the connect string,
[Connection string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpPst.png)

This is my aapp.properties,

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb+srv://jamescervamtes:jamescervantes@theshop.rmeawrn.mongodb.net/TheShop
spring.data.mongodb.database=TheShop
```

I tried everything, and I am just expecting for the app to bee runnning showing me the connect to mongo is made and successful

**EDIT:**

This is the atlas UI

[Atlas Ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1B39.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your connection URL isn't the same as what is listed in the atlas console.

Try setting your properties to this:

```
spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
      uri: mongodb+srv://theshop.rmeawrn.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority
      username: <username>
      password: <password>
      database: TheShop
```

Also, I don't see anywhere in the atlas connection string that references the database.  Are you certain that the database (TheShop) exists on this atlas cluster?

Comment: check my edit, I included the atlas ui, I created a database called TheShop